# What would you see inside a spherical mirror?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, physics, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

Image to build a huge spherical shell made of semitransparent glass, and to cover the internal part with a reflecting material.

In such structure some light can enter, and an observer inside  it (e.g. located at the center of the sphere) could be able to see the reflections of himself on the internal side of the shell.

Let us suppose, additionally, that the space surrounding that structure is virtually empty, in such a way that there is not much overlap between the internal and the external reflections on the surface of the mirror.

> **What would an observer see inside such spherical mirror?**

I tried to approach this problem with elementary Euclidean tools, but I struggle to find any reasonable answer.

Sorry for the naivety, and thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Here's a nice little experiment you can do. Grab a reflective spoon or some other concave object, and hold your finger at a reasonable distance from the inside. You should see your finger reflected upside down (if not maybe you have to flip the spoon around, or hold your finger at a bigger distance). Now slowly move your finger closer to the spoon and observe what happens when you approach its focal point.

Comment: @Peter Thanks Peter, nice suggestion. But everything would change, I guess, if you are *surrounded* by such spoon. I would say that this problem is quantitatively  related to the black body problem, which is way more complex than the experiment you mentioned, although interesting and pertinent.

Comment: Doesn't vsauce have a video answering this exact question?

Comment: @D.Brogan I didn't know vsauce, but I've just watched the video you mentioned, thanks! Very entertaining, but I am looking for a more quantitative analysis or, at least, for an idea how to mathematically approach the problem.

Comment: You can find simulations on the web. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdSC6GwNhN8

Comment: @YvesDaoust Interesting! Although I'm not really fond of Satan : )  However, there's little, if any, information about the mathematics used to build such video. In any case, taking such video as serious, you could see a sort of "quantization" of the reflected image (layers, squares... are the squares related to the pixels of the original image?), which is all in all very intriguing but, again, in absence of a mathematical approach, this is just a video.

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: my bet is that it was rendered by ray tracing, simply using the law of specular reflection.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree. But, then, the whole representation is biased by the computing capacity of the machine they used to perform the calculations, and details as the squares appearing in the video (likely related to the pixels of the "I love Satan" image) can appear or not according to the platform/algorithm/approximation used to calculate it. This is not what I am looking for, although the video is interesting.

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: the pixelization was probably shown on purpose. I don't see why different machines would render differently with identical working parameters, the equations are deterministic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust True, but the problem is analytical, i.e. it deals with real numbers. By means of a computer, you must approximate such numbers up to a *finite precision*, hence the dependency of the platform/algorithm/approximation.

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: an analytical solution will just be intractable because the multiple reflections combine in a complex way and because there is astigmatism, defocusing, caustics, diffraction...

Comment: I see your point. However, I am not interested in simulations (although they can be a fascinating cartoon). I am interested in the mathematical approach to the problem. Do you have any practical suggestion how to sketch out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The BEST Possible answer to your question:
[Vsauce-Inside a spherical mirror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRP82omMX0g)